# How to show Plist data in android listview

Tags: android, listview, dictionary, plist

I have a property-list of Dictionary. Now i want to utilize it in android also. How can i use it to show data in list-view.
Actually i am making a dictionary in android.
I tried to search it, but didn't find any relevant material.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What you have tried yet? You should use SQLite Database for this purpose...

Comment: Database is not available.  I have a number of P-list files, i want use it.

Comment: I can see what you are trying to do , just remember android is not iOS , what you need is string-array not a Plist

Comment: @nizammoidu i want to use plist data in android.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not do this by defult. But there are a few p-list parser libraries for android. Take a look at [android-plist-parser](https://github.com/tenaciousRas/android-plist-parser).

Comment: How can i download this and add to project. I did not get the downloading of this lib process.